# Windchill effect or something else

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life

If I'm driving a fire truck on a cold winter night, given the following factors. Will it create an effect that could freeze the water pump faster than if it were just parked in the same conditions. Does the cold air flowing over the pump reduce the pump temperature below the air temperature?
Air temperature 38 F.
Humidity 40%
MPH 35

Answer (score 1):

Under most circumstances the cooling of of an object in air is mainly due to [convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection), which is due to the circulation of the air. If you blow air at the object you get [forced convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forced_convection) and an enhanced cooling rate.

You will often hear forced convection being referred to as *wind chill*, but this term is a bit misleading. Forced convection won't cool an object to below the temperature of the air. For example if the air temperature is $-5C$ then the object won't cool to below $-5$C no matter how strong the wind. However forced convection will cause the object to cool to $-5$C faster than it would otherwise. In the case of your pump it will make the water in the pump freeze faster.